# Casting error with ConnectionStringSettingsCollection

Tags: c#, .net

I need something like:

```
Configuration cf = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("name_of.exe");
ConnectionStringSettingsCollection s = cf.ConnectionStrings;
```

But this gives an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'ConnectionStringsSection' to 'ConnectionStringsSectionCollection'

When I do:

```
ConnectionStringSettingsCollection s = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;
```

There is no error, but I need the first one, because I'm not using the default configuration file. 
So why does the conversion fail in the first case (and not in the second one)?

EDIT: 
Sorry for confusion but with 'first one' I ment the first code example, not the first connectionstring. For some reason the second code example does cast the connectionsStrings into a ConnectionsStringSettingsCollection, but the first code example does not, that is my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first block of code uses the `Configuration` class, which has a property `ConnectionStrings` which is of type `ConnectionStringsSection` and you're trying to assign this to a `ConnectionStringSettingsCollection` object, which isn't compatible.

The second block of code is trying to assign the same type, `ConnectionStringSettingsCollection` to a property on a static class `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` which is of type `ConnectionStringSettingsCollection`.

Although the names are the same, the properties are of different *types*, see documentation...

[Configuration.ConnectionStrings Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.connectionstrings(v=vs.110).aspx)

> public ConnectionStringsSection ConnectionStrings { get; }

[ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings(v=vs.110).aspx)

> public static ConnectionStringSettingsCollection ConnectionStrings {
>   get; }

Comment: So I had to do:  'ConnectionStringSettingsCollection s = cf.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings !

Answer (score 0):

Updated after Edit to OP:

you are assigning it to a wrong data type, that is why the error;

```
Configuration cf = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("name_of.exe");
ConnectionStringsSection s = cf.ConnectionStrings;
```

The property names are same but they belong to a different type and the property themselves are of different type i.e. first snippet is trying to access `ConnectionStrings` property which belongs to type (class) `Configuration`. The data type of this is `ConnectionStringSection`.

The second snippet is trying to access `ConnectionStrings` property which belongs to they type (class) `ConfigurationManager`. The data type of this is `ConnectionStringSettings`.

Before OP edit:

That's a collection and if you need the first one could you not just use the index 0. Like...

```
ConnectionStringSettings s = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0];
```

to be safer you might want to add count check before accessing it... a better version would be like:

```
ConnectionStringSettings s = (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Count > 0)
                    ? ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0]
                    : null;
```

Explanation:
Your ConnectionStrings is of data type `ConnectionStringSettingsCollection`, which basically means it could hold 0 or more number of `ConnectionStringSettings`. Now if you need the first one, you could specify the index i.e. 0 and it will return you the first `ConnectionStringSettings`. Just be sure to use proper data type or just use `var`